# Showing continous linear functional

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $A$ be the space $L^{1}(R) \cap L^{2}(R)$, and the norm $||u||_{A}=||u||_1 + ||u||_2$.
Then, show that for $\alpha \in (0,1/2)$.

$$ u \rightarrow \int_{R} \frac{1}{|x|^{\alpha}}u(x) dx $$ is a continous linear functional on A.

My attempt:

I am trying to prove this by showing that this is a bounded functional, by using Holder's inequality. Since $u(x) \in A$, $||u||_{1}, ||u||_{2} < \infty$ and hence $||u||_{A} < \infty$. But $\frac{1}{|x|^{\alpha}}$ does not belong to $L^{2}$ or $L^{\infty}$, so I cannot use the Holder with $p=2,q=2$ or $p=\infty,q=1$. Can someone give some hint?

Comment: Split the integral into $0<|x|\le 1$ and   $|x|\ge 1.$ For the first integral apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. The second integral is bounded by $\|u\|_1.$